# What does the option passed at the end of the Systemd command mean?

Tags: linux, systemd, process

I have this ***command***:

```
systemctl restart rh-php71-php-fpm -l
```

I would like to know what the `-l` which is passed at the end of the command corresponds to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-l` is the equivalent of `--full`

It means: Do not ellipsize unit names, process tree entries, journal output, or truncate unit descriptions in the output of status, list-units, list-jobs, and list-timers.

[All parameters can be found here](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/systemctl.1.html).